# ERROR 404 - accessing localhost webpage from android mobile

Tags: android

I have developed a webpage  and hosted it using **tomcat server**.
 I connected my PC to  hot spot of my android mobile.
 I tried to access the webpage hosted on localhost from my mobile browser.
 I got the following error.

```
  HTTP STATUS 404 - [location specified in URL] 
  TYPE : status report
  MESSAGE: [location specified in URL]
  DESCRIPTION : the requested resource is not available
```

I followed as specified in[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)
 what i am missing

what I am missing?

Comment: localhost ? view in mobile ? what are talking about ?

Comment: Instead of localhost, try using your PC's IP (I assume tomcat is hosted in your PC)

Comment: I followed as specified in "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device"

Answer (score 1):

Connect both your PC and phone to the same WiFi network and instead of "localhost" use your PC's IP address and whatever port tomcat is running on.
It'll probably be something like `http://192.168.1.10:8080/`

Comment: This is correct solution!. If this does not work then check config file of Tomcat.

Comment: yes I did that but I get same responese

Comment: All I can say then is make sure your devices are on the same LAN, that your firewall isn't blocking the requests and that you're using the correct IP address and port.

Answer (score 0):

*Localhost* would work only in the local PC. Even if it is mobile emulator, *localhost* would not work.

**Steps to Do:**

Host the tomcat server in your local PC with IP say, 170.17.7.1 and start the server (Possibly in 8080 port).

Try the server URL from the browser say: `http://170.17.7.1:8080/MyWebAppURL` and check if it is getting hit by verifying Tomcat logs.

Now try hitting the URL from your wi-fi enabled mobile Phone.